# Getting the sum of values in a nested dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary structure like:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, double>> temp = 
                                         new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, double>>();
```

I wanted to calculate the sum of all double values in `temp` using LINQ. I have tried to get the list of dictionaries `List<Dictionary<int, double>> res = temp.Values.Select(s => s).ToList();` but no idea how to move forward with this.

Comment: How about this : var results = temp.Select(x => new { key = x.Key, sum = x.Value.Select(y => y.Value).Sum() }).ToList();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to flatten - you can simply get sum of *sum of values* from internal dictionary:

```
var total = temp.Values.Sum(d => d.Values.Sum());
```

Comment: Agree, this looks nicer than my construction.

Comment: great !  you were fast.

Comment: @Sergey Also, what I was trying to do is `var total = temp.Values.Select(d => d.Values.Sum());` Can you tell me why this doesn't give me the expected result?

Comment: @RaksMen you were projecting each value of outer dictionary (i.e. each inner dictionary) to sum of inner dictionary values (i.e. to double value). Result of such projection is `IEnumerable<double>` - sequence of inner sums. You missed just Sum of this sequence. You can add `.Sum()` to end of your query and get same results

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectMany to flatten the nested lists

temp.Values.SelectMany(dict => dict.Values.ToList()).Sum()